# How to generate gas report for a smart contract in Foundry?

Tags: foundry-rs

I am currently working on a project that involves smart contracts deployed on Foundry. I need to generate a gas report for a specific contract to analyze the gas consumption and optimize its efficiency.

Could someone guide me on how to generate a gas report for a contract deployed on Foundry? Are there specific tools or commands that I should be aware of? Additionally, any advice on interpreting and analyzing the gas consumption data would be highly appreciated.